# webgl shaders defined in javascript

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader

The demos I have seen all define shaders in html, and get them by name.  Is there a way in javascript to create them from strings?

Instead of:

```
  var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
```

something like:

```
var fragmentShader = createShader(gl,
"fragment code here "
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shaders : Best practice to store them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111993/shaders-best-practice-to-store-them)

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the existing answers, I don't think, actually answer the question of how to set the source of a WebGL shader from a string in JavaScript. The missing bit is `shaderSource`:

```
const vertexShaderSource = `
attribute vec4 vertexPosition;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vertexPosition;
}
`;

const vertexShader = context.createShader(context.VERTEX_SHADER);
context.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
context.compileShader(vertexShader);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
```

and you can create your own shader program with GLSL in JavaScript like this

```
     var fragmentShaderText =
    [
    'precision mediump float;',
    '',
    'varying vec3 fragColor;',
    'void main()',
    '{',
    '   gl_FragColor = vec4(fragColor, 1.0);',
    '}',
    ].join('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have seen so far:

```
var vertexShader = `attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
}`;
```